# No such file or directory in R studio

Tags: r

what's wrong with my code I can not open the file in r studio

```
location = "C:/R/Practice/practice1"

filename = paste(location,"SDG20200430.CSV",sep="/")

HAPPY <- read.table(filename, header=TRUE, sep=",")


> HAPPY <- read.table(filename, header=TRUE, sep=",")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/R/Practice/practice1/SDG20200430.CSV': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is your C:/ protected from being accessed by other applications?

Comment: (1) You "should" use `file.path` instead of `paste` when constructing paths. What you have does not appear to be the problem, though. (2) Does `list.files(location)` include your CSV file name?

Comment: location = "C:/Users/82109/Desktop/same/SDG20200430.CSV"

filename = file.path(location,"SDG20200430.CSV",sep="/")

Mydata <- read.table(filename, header=TRUE, sep=",")

Comment: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/82109/Desktop/same/SDG20200430.CSV/SDG20200430.CSV/': No such file or directory

Comment: I still can not find what's wrong with it.....is there any possibility that the actual file is wrong?

Comment: If you have, try loading from a different drive E:/ or F:/ and see. Also, try using \\ instead of /.

Comment: Try with read.csv as well